# Use libvirt to configure KVM guest with user defined tap device

Tags: networking, linux-kvm, libvirt

As far as I know, if we set up kvm guest OS with libvirt, it will automatically create bridge device virbr0, and tap device vnet0 which represents VM guest nic (and of course vnet0 is attached to virbr0).

Although what I want is to bind VM guest to a user defined tap device, e.g. my-tap0

Or, can I control the way libvirt creates the tap device? (mac address, nic name, etc.)

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance and I welcome any suggestion!

Comment: problem solved! modify block <target dev='my-tap0'/> gives tap device I intended.

Comment: Go on this google page u will some interesting....https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WzQ9JRtyvbjnPa0fnBWCQhQeXZNL3JHfiIWA0_wtxzc/edit hope it will suits yr requirement